# Не отображается textView state_pressed(state_focused)

Tags: android, android-textview, android-dialog

Всем привет, вопрос такой. У меня не работает drawable state_focused и state_pressed для диалогов, сколько пытаюсь ничего не помогают. С кнопками все работает отлично а вот для текстов не работает. Что делать?

созданный java класс
Material Dialog.java

```
package biz.galamat.simpleinsta;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MaterialDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Context mContext;
    public MaterialDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text1.setOnClickListener(this);
        text2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

xml файл для диалога

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_up"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:text="Удалить"
        android:textColor="@color/dialog_listview_color"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_down"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:text="Отключить уведомления"
        android:textColor="@color/dialog_listview_color"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

один drawable файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dialog_on_hold_color">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/dialog_on_hold_color" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/dialog_on_hold_color">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/dialog_on_hold_color" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"         android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Порядок поменяйте. item без стейтов сделайте последним. При смене стейта берется первый (по порядку) подходящий item, у вас он всегда один и тот же, т.к. подходит под любой стейт.

Answer (score 1):

помогла обертка в linear layout, с теми же параметрами